# Difference between standard price and the overall average standard price of all products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running this query basically word for word from the book.

Provide a listing of all of the products that includes the difference between its standard price and the overall average standard price of all products.

```
SELECT ProductStandardPrice – PriceAvg AS Difference
FROM Product_T, (SELECT AVG(ProductStandardPrice) AS PriceAvg
FROM Product_T);
```

I keep getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3  Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: Your error is a SQL Server error; only tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Your specific error is because you don't have a table alias.  I also abhor commas in the `FROM` clause, so:

```
SELECT (t.ProductStandardPrice – a.PriceAvg) AS Difference
FROM Product_T t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(ProductStandardPrice) AS PriceAvg
      FROM Product_T
     ) a;
```

However, the best way to answer this question is to use window functions:

```
SELECT (t.ProductStandardPrice – AVG(t.ProductStandardPrice) OVER () 
       ) AS Difference
FROM Product_T t ;
```

Comment: Please explain what the comma (or Cartesian Joins) represents in the FROM clause.

Comment: @clifton_h . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a question,not in a comment.  However, I think any SQL tutorial or database documentation covers Cartesian products.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you will note the button says "Add Comment" and not "Add more questions" but i digress. [Technet - Using Cross Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) was the first result when googling Cartesian Joins SQL Server. So yes, there are documentations on the subject

Comment: My hope was you would improve the answer since an old style join syntax has newer JOIN alternatives including the cross or cartesian join.